# Display windows present in different storyboards

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, xcode8

I'm using Xcode 8 and storyboards for mac development.

I have 2 `storyboard`s with `NSWindowController` in each of them.

**1).** How can I display both windows when the app is launched?

**2).** How can I display window on pressing button on other window?

---

**Edit:**

**Code:**

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
{
    let st = NSStoryboard(name: "Logs", bundle: nil) // Logs is my storyboard name
    var logWindow: NSWindowController? = nil       
    logWindow = st.instantiateInitialController() as! NSWindowController?
    if logWindow?.window?.isVisible == false
    {
        logWindow?.window?.setIsVisible(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just turn on Visible At Launch?

Comment: @ElTomato I selected that option for windows in both storyboards but it didn't work.

Comment: Make a reference to a window controller in AppDelegate and set its window with setIsVisible.

Comment: @ElTomato I just started mac development so sorry if my issue is dumb but I can't `ctrl` drag the window controller to app delegate. So how can I do that?

Comment: I saw your comment in @ElTomato answer before he removed it. Can you post your code once? I want to look at it.

Comment: @SkrewEverything I have added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is correct but the problem is with `logWindow`.

I assume, you know that the local variable is dead after the execution of method.

As you can see `logWindow` is a local variable. When `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)` is executing, the variable is alive, a new window is created and also displayed.

When `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)` is finished executing, your variable `logWindow` is not alive. So, the allocated memory is de-allocated automatically (by ARC) and the window is destroyed/de-allocated.

All this is happening so fast and it is the reason you are not seeing the window inspite of `isVisible()` returning `true`(it returns `true` because the method is still in execution and `logWindow` is still alive).

So just make `logWindow` a variable of class(in what ever class you are trying to display the window) and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for nice and detailed explanation.

Comment: I just realised most of your questions are answered by me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Both questions boil down to pretty much the same thing: *How can I display a window from a storyboard?* Whether you want to do it when the app is launched or when the user clicks a button shouldn't really affect what you need to do to display the window.

Take a look at the [`NSStoryboard` class](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsstoryboard) and you'll find methods for instantiating a window controller from a storyboard. So, create an instance of `NSStoryboard` if you don't already have one, and then use that to instantiate the window controller in question. For example, if your window controller is called "My Window Controller" and is located in the main storyboard...

```
let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let windowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "My Window Controller") as! NSWindowController
```

Then do whatever you like with `windowController`. If you want to display two windows when the app is launched, then maybe your app delegate has two properties for keeping track of the corresponding window controllers. In your app delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching(notification:)` method, you could create two windows using code like I've shown and assign the window controllers to those windows. If you want to open a window when the user clicks a button, put code like the code above in the button's action, and store a reference to the resulting window controller in some appropriate object, possibly the window controller where the action appears.

Comment: And how can I close that window if I want to?

Comment: Again, look at [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nswindowcontroller). `NSWindowController` has a `close` method you can call.